# FlowLayout in Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout

This is my layout.

[image]

**The two radio button should be below the welcome label.**

like this:

```
__________________________
|                        | 
|        WELCOME         |
|         *  *           |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|________________________|
```

the two asterisk are the radio buttons.

My Code:

```
northpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
northpanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));


northpanel.add(welcome);  //this welcome text label

northpanel1.add(r1);   //this radio 1
northpanel1.add(r2);   //this radio 2


add(northpanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(northpanel1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Comment: Hpw to get the two radio buttons below the WELCOME label

Comment: Solution: Don't use FlowLayout. Use BorderLayout for the main container and then the central container should use GridLayout to hold the JRadioButtons.

Comment: Just a question, what is the arrow like button to the left of the minimize button on the titlebar ?

Comment: oh that is the teamviewer software adds it to windows so i can share to other people that specific window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `northpanel` and `northpanel` to a `panel` having `GridLayout(0, 1)` then

```
add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: the welcome label however is pushed far left on the screen but the 2 radio buttons are centralised as needed

Comment: @user2016977: Try `FlowLayout.CENTER` on the welcome panel, as SoboLAN [shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14838145/230513).

Answer (score 5):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class StackOverflow14837740
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable ()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                createAndShowGUI ();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI ()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (2, 1));

        JPanel welcomePanel = new JPanel (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER));      
        welcomePanel.add (new JLabel ("Welcome"));

        northPanel.add (welcomePanel);

        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton ("Button 1", true);
        JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton ("Button 2", false);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup ();
        group.add (button1);
        group.add (button2);

        radioPanel.add (button1);
        radioPanel.add (button2);

        northPanel.add (radioPanel);

        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (3, 3));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                middlePanel.add (new JButton ("Button " + i + j));
            }
        }

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER));

        southPanel.add (new JLabel ("Whose turn:"));
        southPanel.add (new JButton ("Reset"));

        frame.add (northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add (middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add (southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack ();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

It looks like this (although you have to resize it a bit):

[image: printscreen]

Comment: wow..thank you so much..i am really amazed by the efforts put in the answers by this community!! keep up the good work! :)

Comment: @user2016977 That's because the community is huge (hundreds of thousands of people)... ooh, and because we're awesome :D .

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add more than one component to a `BorderLayout` region and you are doing it in the end. You need to change your `northpanel` to be a `BorderLayout`, then put your welcome text and `northtestpanel1` inside it, like this:

```
 northpanel -> BorderLayout, JFrame's NORTH position
 welcome -> northpanel NORTH position
 northpanel1 -> FlowLayout, northpanel CENTER position
```

You may have problems about put `welcome` in the center (I'm just guessing, maybe it will working fine). If you don't have any solution to it, just wrap it into a new `JPanel` and use the `FlowLayout` with `FlowLayout.CENTER`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use GridLayout OR GridBagLayout instead of Flow-layout.First set GridBagLayout of northpanel and then add your required components,let say your radio buttons and wellcome label. For more detail you can consult [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).